# AVAudioUnit (render) callback

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio, ios8, audiounit

I'm trying to do some audio processing with the new AVAudioUnits / AVAudioNodes. As the AVAudioUnits expose their underlying (classic CA) AudioUnit, I assumed I could simply attach a render callback as always, but the callback never gets called.

Here’s the code I’m talking about:

```
AVAudioUnitReverb *reverbUnit = [[AVAudioUnitReverb alloc] init];

AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallbackStruct;
renderCallbackStruct.inputProc = &myRenderCallback;
renderCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = myAudioStruct;

AudioUnitSetProperty(reverbUnit.audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &renderCallbackStruct, sizeof(renderCallbackStruct));
```

And the render callback looks basically like the following:

```
OSStatus myRenderCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData) {
    printf("callback!");
    return noErr;
}
```

The reverbUnit is of course attached to the engine (`PlayerNode -> Reverb -> MainMixer`) and I can hear the audio from the player (reverberated) as expected.

Note: When I set the callback via

```
AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(reverbUnit, &myRenderCallback, myAudioStruct)
```

it gets called, but then the `ioData->mBuffers[0].mData` is nil (which is correct AFAIK), so this is not an alternative.

Comment: Do not use any print function such as printf or NSLog. It is a performance bottle neck.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I know. But that’s not the problem here. A real callback obviously wouldn’t look like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The render callback gets over-ridden by the connecting the input node of the reverb unit in the AUGraph.  You can only have one input to a reverb node, either an input node or a render callback.

Comment: Hopefully on topic: Can one create a AVAudioUnit with a custom callback to use in an AVAudioEngine?